# HTML page in a webbrowser control wrong behavior

Tags: c#, html, wpf, browser

I have a C#-WPF application which I placed a web browser in it. in the solution I have also index.html file and also a js file. the HTML has some calls to the javascript file.
and has the following tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript charset="utf-8" src="myfile.js"></script>
```

in my xaml.cs I have the following code:

```
webBrowser.Source = new Uri("hard-coded path to the HTML file");
```

when I run this code I get an error "An error has occured in the script on this page, object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"

but when I clicked only on the same HTML file and run it in a broweser, there is no error.

what can cause this behavior? what is wrong in my C# code? Any idea??

thanks

Comment: When you say: "when I clicked only on the same HTML file and run it in a broweser, there is no error" - were you using Internet Explorer or something else? If IE, do you have debugging turned on?

Comment: IE, with no debugging (I disabled all)

Comment: So maybe the fact that you don't see the error in browser is because debugging is disabled, but in the application the WebHost is ignoring the settings (or Visual Studio coerces debugging). Run from web browser with debugging and see if there's an error. I suspect it's IE's behavior.

Comment: no, I've run it with and without debugging. IE has no error

Comment: Sorry, I'm stumped. The only thing I can think of is that VS uses a different (older) version of IE for its debugging.

Comment: I have a similar issue. In IE works just fine but in WebBrowser I get that javascript 'addeventlistener' error. You are right it uses IE7:   User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/7.0; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; SLCC2; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)

Answer (score 0):

> I get an error "An error has occured in the script on this page,
>   object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'"

This error happens because you embded webbrowser could not find address of `myfile.js`.so for this problem you can put java scrip file in source

so do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript charset="utf-8" src="AddressLocation\myfile.js"></script>
```

Change with:

```
<script type="text/javascript>
//add content of your java file here
</script>
```